# How to represent number as image?

Tags: vb.net

I have something like this :

```
If txt1.Text = "abc" Then
   txt2.Text = "11111"
End If
```

After this code executed I want to convert that "11111" = square something like image below 
[image]

This is for web application

Comment: How does "11111" relate to colors? What are other possible combinations?

Comment: yeah 1 is green something like that

Comment: and 1 is blue and 1 is yellow etc.? all your number are the same but the colors  the image are different

Comment: ops sorry, that question had been editted. tq

Comment: Where is the decoder ring?

Comment: what is decoder ring ? huhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have 2 images "1.jpg" which is green, and "0.jpg" which is black (add more colors and numbers if your string need to support more).

Build an HTML string based on your `txt2.Text` text:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each c as Char in txt2.Text.Chars
   sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}.jpg' />", c)
Next
```

Place a Literal control on the page where you want images to display and output HTML there:

```
Literal1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: how if i want to convert * to image i cannot save file as * ?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to save displayed image?

Comment: if my txt2.Text = 11**222, i want to convert * as image too and i cannot save my display image as *.jpg

Comment: Then do something like `sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}.jpg' />", if(c = "*", "s"c, c))` and have image "s.jpg" representing the star

Comment: If I have this in my txt2.Text = 111234567 and i want to assign 2,3,4,5,6,7 as s.jpg how ?

Comment: no, `s.jpg` will represent just just star `*`. for normal numbers use `2.jpg`,`3.jpg`, etc.

Comment: what if I want to display that image which is 11111 in one table which is 1 row, 5 column ?

Comment: How does it display now? One image below other? Not all in one row? Or did you mean 1 columns, 5 rows?

Comment: 1 image in 1 column and lastly it will be like block

Comment: 1 image inside 1 row and 1 column, then the other is inside 1 row and 1 column for example 456 then the image for 4 is (1,1) the image for 5 is (1,2) the image for 6 (1,3)